# Забанен ip-адрес сервера, как использовать ip другого сервера

Tags: exim, email, debian

Здравствуйте, так случилось, что забанили ip-сервер, где лежат сайты и почта перестала доходить до адресата. Есть еще один сервер, как можно через его ip пересылать почту?
Оба сервера на ОС Debian почтовик Exim.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, для начала нужен не другой сервер: 
 1. А нужно выяснить, кто рассылает спам (это скорее всего вирус в локалке).
 2. Вывести с блек листинга на сайте mxtoolbox.com
Ну, вроде и все.

---

так же можно посмотреть кто обращаеться к порту 25
например:
$ sudo tcpdump -n -i eth1 tcp port 25
eth1 - интерфейс сетевой карты (у вас он может быть другой)
проверить можно через:
$ ifconfig

желательно наблюдать за внутренним интерфейсом, так как спам летит с внутренней сети.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но как же перенаправить почту?

Answer (score 0):

Из 2-го сделать прокси-сервер или vpn и работать через него.

Comment: Вот если бы помогли настроить, я, к сожалению, не силен в этом.